# Tableau Desktop delete calculated fields

Tags: tableau-api

Hi I was in the process of creating a calculated filed in my tableau desktop 2018.2 and I figured later that I no longer needed it, but i can't seem to delete it. Any solutions?

I have posted a picture of my current calculated fields.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of going to the Analysis menu, right click on the field itself in the Dimension or Measures section and select Delete.

[image]